# Cannot Update Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Tags: 12.04, software-center, update-manager, lts

When I am running update, I cannot update Due to this error;

```
/*W:GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com squeeze Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E0F72778C4676186, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/artfwo/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources : 404  Not Found
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: have tried changing the update server location ?

Comment: what command did your? `sudo apt-get update` or you want to install `playonlinux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that the **Public Key** for that Repository was not Imported.

To Import Public Key run;

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com E0F72778C4676186
```

Then run update.